# Comparing two equal expressions in c# return false

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

Can anybody explain why this always return "false"?
myList contains ".txt", and the extension is ".txt".

```
Array.Exists(myList, element => element == Path.GetExtension(myName).ToLower())
```

I even try things like:

```
String.Compare(myList[10],".txt")
```

And I still get "false" (1).
When I check the value of `myList[10]`, it contains ".txt"

**EDIT:**
I could narrow down the problem a little bit.
myList comes from an xml:

```
                myXml= new XDocument();
                myXml= XDocument.Load(myXmlFilePath);

            myList= myXml.Root.Elements("File")
                   .Select(element => element.Value)
                   .ToArray();
```

If I replace
 `myXml= XDocument.Load(myXmlFilePath);`
 with
 `myXml= XDocument.Parse("<Files><File>.txt</File><File>.ppt</File></Files>");`
 than it works well

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Files>
    <File>.txt </File>
    <File>.ppt </File>
    <File>.xls </File>
</Files>
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. We don't have enough information to help you at the moment. I suspect the problem is that the value actually contains something *as well* as `.txt`, but we can't tell.

Comment: what's the type of `myList` ?

Comment: @yogi: Presumably a `string[]`, otherwise the `Compare` call would fail.

Comment: @yogi, it is public static string[] myList.

Comment: @JonSkeet: if(Array.Exists(myList, element => element == Path.GetExtension(myName).ToLower())){ <do some stuff>}. myName is a file name. for example a.txt, b.pdf, etc..

Comment: @user990635 To clarify, Jon was asking for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Something that we can paste into a console application and test it ourselves.

Comment: @dcastro thanks for the comment :) I added an "edit". hope it helps

Comment: That suggests the problem is in the XML... which we can't see. My guess is that there's some unprintable character in there, or it's in some incorrect encoding. Try printing the length of `myList[10]`... I suspect it won't be 4. Either way, we can't really help you without seeing the troublesome data.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.Exists` Determines whether the specified array contains elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate.
I would assume your predicate `element => element == Path.GetExtension(myName).ToLower()`, comes out as false.
`String.Compare` assumed that your `myList[10]` is char array as [there's no overload to pass actual array to this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

My guess would be that your premise is wrong and `myName` is not path to text file, and `myList[10]` is char array and not string array.